# Text is not wrapping inside absolute positioned div

Tags: html, css, text, word-wrap

I'm having an issue getting text to wrap inside an absolute positioned div. I think the problem is I have a the width set to 100% which I have to have because the div resizes with the page. How can I get the text to wrap.

Here's my code:

```css
#content {
  background: black;
  min-height: 60px;
  background: #0a0a0a;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#content .entry {
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  text-wrap: normal;
  top: 0;
  left: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 50px;
  border-left: 1px solid #262626;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div class="entry">
    <-----text---->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Put a div without specific widths set inside of the 100% width div. This will give the div a "preset" width and not a 100% width but it would still be the same width.

Comment: That doesn't seem to change anything. The problem is the div extends 200px past it's parent div because I have it positioned 200px from the left inside the parent.

Comment: please provide the html, that would make debugging easier

Comment: I gave the div we added padding-right of 220px to make up for it which works. Not pretty but it works. Put as an answer if you want.

Comment: I think the id="entry" in the html should be a class="entry", right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you declare a width of 100% AND a left of 400px on the .entry elements. The total width will be 100% + 400px which will make the .entry element wider than its container. It does wrap its text, but you won't see the rightmost 400px of it.

The problem is that you cannot define the width and the padding/margin/left/right/etc on the same element. You need a nested structure to get it done. So, add an extra div in the content > entry html structure and define the width on the first one and the padding on the second.

Comment: The problem with that is `.entry` won't extend the width of the parent unless there is enough text to reach the end width of the parent. You can see here. http://jsfiddle.net/gp8p4/2/

Comment: Ah I see. Can you add an extra '<div>' in between the entry and the content?

Comment: and then give the .entry padding-right to make up for the amount it extends. Yeah.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that you cannot define the width and the padding/margin/left/right/etc on the same element. You need a nested structure to get it done.

Comment: yeah thats what we worked through in the comments above. Change your answer to reflect this and I'll accept it.